# The correct positioning of a sentence adverb in a sentence

Tags: grammar, adverbs, adverb-position

> - Three days? I think that it is not **simply** enough time.
> - Three days? I think that it is **simply** not enough time

What rule of grammar informs acceptable *word order* in this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've been traditional in my amending of the title. I'd prefer 'pragmatic marker', of course. And for 'nearly' in '[not] nearly enough time', 'quantifier pre-modifier'.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Many apologies. I've traced the true culprits. Please have an extra glass of wine and forgive me.

Comment: @Paul Amerigo Pajo and Urbycoz: Why did you delete 'sentence adverb' from the former edit? 'Simply' as used here is not a classical adverb. The fact that it is a 'sentence adverb' (or, in some modern and I believe better analyses, a 'pragmatic marker') rather than a central adverb is important. It affects positioning. I trust you understand this? 'Frankly, I'd speak to her' is different from 'I'd speak frankly to her'. Your editing here is unhelpful. I'd make very sure of your facts before you make any further attempts.

Answer (score 2):

In

> Three days? I think that it is not nearly enough time.

'nearly' is premodifying the quantifier 'enough' and needs to immediately precede it.

But in

> Three days? I think that it is simply not enough time.

'simply' is not modifying 'enough' (or indeed much else): it's a pragmatic marker (probably marking the speaker's exasperation). It sounds wrong anywhere but before the 'not'. 'Frankly' is often used the same way (but is far more mobile in the sentence).

In contrast, with

> Three days? I simply think that it is not enough time.

'simply' could be a speech-act-modifying (here, contextualising: a single thought on the issue) pragmatic marker, meaning 'merely'.

Comment: "that it" is wrong.  "Three days? I think that is simply not enough time" or more likely in speech "Three days? I think that's simply not enough time"

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect: 21.8 million Google hits for "it is enough time". 15.5 million for "that it is enough time". 3.5 million for "think that it is enough time".

Comment: object - that it

Comment: An animal. I think that it is an elephant. 'that it is an elephant' – complement clause. // 'Three days? That's not enough!' 'I think that it is [enough] [time] [for you to complete the task]'.

Comment: In your example, you're thinking about the "an animal".  **in the example, he is not thinking about the 'three days', he's thinking about another issue (which happens to include the three day concept).**

Comment: frickin' weird isn't it ?  :O

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow the half-deleted debate above, but I agree with Joe that the ‘it’ here feels strained (though I wouldn't say wrong per se). The distance the preceding statement of “three days”, from the embedded clause across the main clause “I think”, seems too great to support such a weak pronoun. _That_ does sound much better to me, too. Moreover, there is the fact that English (like many other languages) tends to negate speech and opinion verbs, rather than their object clauses, so an even more natural phrasing would be, “I simply don't think that's enough time.”

Answer (score 1):

> It is simply not enough time.

is more correct. The location of "simply" determines the emphasis in the sentence; placed here, it refers to "not enough time".

Comment: indeed it's modifying the "not".  but it's likely what the OP wants is it is modyfing his "thinking", ie, "I certainly think that .." "I am very sure that..."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a critical aspect of this, thanks to the discussion with Edwin.

(Sorry if I did not make this clear below.)

In this example:

"An elephant. I think it has four legs."

**Note that the "it" literally refers to the elephant.**

You are "thinking about" "the elephant".

In this example:

"Three days.  I think: that is not enough time for us to drive"

What you're "thinking about" is the "driving to patagonia issue".

Note for example,

"Three days. I think: we better hurry."  makes perfect sense; the "three days" is not used, at all, in the "thought you're having".

In the elephant example the preliminary sentence is, indeed, the subject of the "thought description."

In the 'three days' example, it's just a poetic intro, which, happens to "also be" mentioned, in the, uh, thought description. The actual subject of the thought description is "driving to patagonia".

---

Note that what you are **actually saying** is:

I think: < the following thought >

So, what is  < the following thought > ?

< the following thought > == "three days is not enough time"

Now, when you "think" something, you can modify that:

I think, quickly, X.

I think, drunkenly, X.

I think, simply, X.

I think, only, X.

I think, ridiculously, X.

So what you're (*almost certainly*) "actually" wanting to say here is:

I think, simply, three days is not enough time.

Or if you prefer for clarity: I think, simply: three days is not enough time.

( You could even, sometimes, put that in quotes, because you are thinking it "as words" ...

I think to myself, simply ... "Three days is not enough time." )

Now, instead of "three days is not enough time", sure, you could say "that is not enough time".  ("that" == "a previously-mentioned thingy" in this case.)

So,

> Three days? I think, simply, that is not enough time.

or indeed

> Three days? I simply think that is not enough time.

(similar forms are "Three days? I frankly think that is not enough time."

That being said, it's wholly common in English to move the "simply" over to the "not".

Three days - that's simply not enough time.

simply is now modifying the "not".  that's decisively not enough time, that's surely not enough time, that's absolutely not enough time, that's perhaps not enough time ... and so on.

(or if you want to pointlessly explain you are thinking...)

Three days - I think that's simply not enough time.